# Multiline data from CSV file is converted to single line in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, csv, pyspark, databricks

I am writing some data from CSV file to SQLMI using Scala on Databricks platform.

the data looks something like this:

```
This is 
Multiline 
data
having many lines of text.
```

The target column type is Varchar

The issue is that this Multiline data when written to SQL is in a single line and the formatting(newlines) are not preserved.

the data when queries from SQL is shown as below

```
This is Multiline data having many lines of text.
```

Is there a way we can preserve the formatting and the data should display on multiple lines when queried in SQL Server.

the code used to write the data is as below:

```
%scala

val d = spark.sql("select * from mytable")
val bulkCopyConfig = Map(
                         "url"             -> myurl,
                         "databaseName"    -> mydb,
                         "user"            -> myuser,
                         "password" -> mypwd,
                         "dbTable" -> mytable,
                         "batchsize" -> "1000",
                         "tableLock" -> "true",
                         "queryTimeout" -> "5000",
                         "schemaCheckEnabled" -> "false",
                         "truncate" -> "true")
d.write.mode("overwrite").options(bulkCopyConfig).format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark").save()
```

Comment: What are you viewing the query results in?  SQL Server doesn't strip newlines on INSERTs or UPDATEs.  I think this is probably more an issue that whatever is displaying your results is not displaying newlines.

Comment: I am querying the data in SSMS viewing the results both in text and grid giving the same result. Text is shown on single line

Comment: I have tried ingesting the data through ADF directly as well with same results. could it be something to do with the bulk insert engine or something ???

Comment: The multiline "CSV" data posted in the question is just multiline text. There's a proper, RFC-defined way to write multiline field values into CSV files, ref: [RFC 4180 https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt). Approach your tool vendor to find out why they're not supporting it.

Comment: the CSV file appears to be formatted correctly. Still the loaded data shows in single line. Probably the bulkload from databricks removed all formatting ??

Answer (score 0):

Solved My problem. the issue was that we were replacing \n character in our code for another bug to fix. I worked that around now to fix this issue.